# SQL trigger changes makes changes only at database

Tags: sql, enums, prestashop, database-trigger

I have added trigger for my database:

```
BEGIN
UPDATE ps_product SET visibility = 'search' WHERE id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM ps_stock_available WHERE quantity = 0 AND id_product_attribute = 0);
UPDATE ps_product SET visibility = 'both' WHERE id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM ps_stock_available WHERE quantity > 0 AND id_product_attribute = 0);
END
```

I have product with visibility "both". Then I change his quantity to 0 via backoffice.

After this in database at table ps_stock_available I can see that visiblity for this product had changed (trigger theoretically worked) for "search".

But at backoffice and frontoffice it is not working correctly:

- BO: edit product -> options -> visibility is still "both",
- FO: product is visible both at category page and search results.

What could be wrong in this code?
When for test I changed trigger for example like:

```
UPDATE ps_product SET visibility = 'search12345678'
```

trigger is not working at all. PS 1.7.5

Comment: you should add the complete trigger code and tag the correct database system you are using.. Trigger code is pretty much database vendor specific

Comment: Also see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.

Comment: Change two products. does the first start working correctly when you change the second?